# How do I sort an array of integers in php or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting

Given an array of integers sort the array such that `arr1 >= arr2 <= arr3 >= arr4 <= arr5 ...` then return array

Example:

Given `[1,2,3,4]`

Possible results:

1: `[2,1,4,3]`

2: `[4,1,3,2]`

Comment: Is this theoretical (ie. sorting algorithms), or did you have a particular language in mind?

Comment: Come to think of it, this question does not make sense.  You are given a sorted array and are expecting one of two unsorted arrays?

Comment: I need an algorithm written either in php or javascript

Comment: You should have [searched google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sort+function+implementation) instead of asking a stack overflow question. If you expect help on here, you have to show more effort (ie. provide the start of an implementation) and ask for specific guidance.

Comment: Sort them, then cut in half, reverse the right side, and merge

Comment: Then google one. Plenty to choose from. SO is not there to solve exercises for you.

Comment: @JonathanWilson and Mär: it looks like you just did not read the question carefully ‍♂️

Comment: @zerkms Perhaps you read it *too* carefully!

Comment: @JonathanWilson well, it's helpful to read and try to understand what OP meant, not just judge them blindly or LMGTFY. Not everyone can express their thoughts clearly due to language issues or lack of experience, neither is a reason to punish them.

Comment: @zerkms You're right. Perhaps I should take a break from reading new questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would implement it, the most naive way:

```
const arr = [4, 2, 1, 3, 5];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

const left = sorted.slice(0, sorted.length / 2);
const right = sorted.slice(sorted.length / 2);

const merged = [];

for (let i = 0; i < right.length; ++i) {
  merged.push(right[i]);
  if (i < left.length) {
    merged.push(left[i]);
  }
}

console.log(merged);
```

What it does:

1. It first sorts the array, to ensure it's totally ordered
2. Then it splits it to 2 sides, as evenly as possible: left and right. For odd count of items the right would be longer
3. Then it merges them from either side one after another

Visual explanation:

Initial state:

```
left        right
[1, 2]      [3, 4, 5]
```

Merging:

Step 1:

```
left        right
[1, 2]      [4, 5]

merged
[3]
```

Step 2:

```
left        right
[2]         [4, 5]

merged
[3, 1]
```

Step 3:

```
left        right
[2]         [5]

merged
[3, 1, 4]
```

Step 4:

```
left        right
[]          [5]

merged
[3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Step 5:

```
left        right
[]          []

merged
[3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zerkms, your solution worked and pretty fast too. 

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a sorted array:

```
sort($numbers);
```

Append numbers to your result array by alternating between taking numbers from the beginning and end of the input array.

```
$i = 1;

// remove elements from $numbers array until it is empty
while ($numbers) {

    if ($i++ % 2) {

        // on odd iterations, pull an item from the end of $numbers (highest numbers)
        $result[] = array_pop($numbers);
    } else {

        // on even iterations, pull an item from the beginning of $numbers (lowest numbers)
        $result[] = array_shift($numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DontPanic your solution is good, but there's a bug. You should Pre-increment `$i` rather than Post-increment.

Comment: Oh, wouldn't that put a lower number first?

Comment: @DontPanic No it wouldn't, it'll actually put the highest number first, because on first iteration using Pre-increment your modulus if statement will look like 1 / 2 with that you have a remainder.

Comment: For the record though, after the bug fix your solution runs faster and it's the one I'll go for. Thanks. 

Comment: Oops, yeah, you're right. I had rewritten it differently from the example I was running to make it more clear, but accidentally switched things around in the process.